# Homeomorphic metric spaces implies isometric bounded real functions spaces?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I received the following exercise in a basic topology course:

> Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be homeomorphic metric spaces. Show that $B(X,\mathbb{R})$ and $B(Y,\mathbb{R})$ are isometric.

I assume the exercise should've mentioned we need to show that $B(X,\mathbb{R})$ and $B(Y,\mathbb{R})$ are isometric with the $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ norm because that's what we usually use but I'm not sure.

I am clueless on how to approach this, I thought about defining something natural like $$\Phi: B(X,\mathbb{R}) \to B(Y,\mathbb{R}), \Phi (g) = g \circ f^{-1}$$
For $f :X \to Y$ the given homeomorphism. But I don't think it helps.

Looking for a hint.

Comment: I think you made a good start. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Klaus I don't see any relationship between distance in $d_Y$ to distance in $d_X$

Comment: Note that you only have a homeomorphism (not an isometry). The metrics $d_X$ and $d_Y$ are useless information. The only important metric here is the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. the absolute value), which is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it helps. Note that\begin{align}\|g_1\circ f^{-1}-g_2\circ f^{-1}\|_\infty&=\sup_{y\in Y}|g_1(f^{-1}(y))-g_2(f^{-1}(y))|\\&=\sup_{x\in X}|g_1(x)-g_2(x)|\\&=\|g_1-g_2\|_\infty.\end{align}

Comment: aren't you assuming that $d_Y, d_X$ are both the absolute value here?

Comment: No. I am just assuming that the distance on $\Bbb R$ is the usual one, induced by the absolute value.

Comment: So we don't even need $f$ to be an homeomorphism? any invertible function will do?

Comment: That is indeed correct.

Comment: @Klaus Sure. I missed that.